# Is it possible to perform an action on NavigationLink tap?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple View showing a list of 3 items. When the user taps on an item, it navigates to the next view. This works fine. However, I would like to also perform an action (set a variable in a View Model) when a list item is tapped.

Is this possible? Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SportSelectionView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var workoutSession: WorkoutManager
    
    let sports = ["Swim", "Bike", "Run"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List(sports, id: \.self) { sport in
            
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView().environmentObject(workoutSession)) {
                
                Text(sport)

            }
        }.onAppear() {
            // Request HealthKit store authorization.
            self.workoutSession.requestAuthorization()
        }
    }
}


struct DisciplineSelectionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SportSelectionView().environmentObject(WorkoutManager())
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65057669/12299030?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that is a little different than the `onAppear` approach.  By creating your own Binding for `isActive` in the `NavigationLink`, you can introduce a side effect when it's set.  I've implemented it here all within the view, but I would probably do this in an `ObservableObject` if I were really putting it into practice:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var _navLinkActive = false
    
    var navLinkBinding : Binding<Bool> {
        Binding<Bool> { () -> Bool in
            return _navLinkActive
        } set: { (newValue) in
            if newValue {
                print("Side effect")
            }
            _navLinkActive = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: Text("Dest"),
                isActive: navLinkBinding,
                label: {
                    Text("Navigate")
                })
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I've found to get around this issue is to add an .onAppear call to the destination view of the NavigationLink. Technically, the action will happen when the ContentView() appears and not when the NavigationLink is clicked.. but the difference will be milliseconds and probably irrelevant.

```
NavigationLink(destination:
                        ContentView()
                            .environmentObject(workoutSession)
                            .onAppear {
                                // add action here
                            }
        )
```